# Hot to show the Time difference between current time and some specified time value

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, eclipse, android-studio

I would like to show the difference of current time and some specified time value in an textview of my offline webpage ( or since it is for my app, would be much better if for android studio ) . How can I achieve this.
Consider I have specified time value is 
10:40 and 12:35

Now If current time is 10:15 , then in textView it must show that 25 minutes left and once time exceeds 10:40 then on same textView it must show how much time is left between current time and 12:35?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the difference using the `Date` object. Here is an example:

```
var d2 = new Date("2017-07-29 10:40");
var d1 = new Date("2017-07-29 10:15");

// result will be 25
var = differenceInMinutes = (d2-d1)/1000/60;
```

PS: As the result is in milliseconds, you need to divide by 1000. And to get the result in minutes you divide by 60.

To refer the current date just don't specify the parameter.

```
var currentDate = new Date();
```

Comment: well that is the half part of battle and how to show the results in textView and once it is already 10:40 i.e once it shows the time difference between d2 and d1, d1 will be the same as current time but now d2 now must be 12:35 and show the time difference in same textView..How can I do that??

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Spilt the current time to "10" and "15".
2. Spilt the specified time to "10" and "40".
3. absolute(10 - 10)  * 60 + absolute(40 - 15).
```

Then you can get the correct answer:25.
You can implement the three steps above in a method by java, which returns an integer value.
:)

Comment: I'm very much new to coding world, it would be much better if you could edit the code for same. I get the idea but no coding skills.